# JQuery Check All & Enable Fields Not Working Together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery script that is used to manage a large treeview of inputs with the ability to enable/disable certain inputs. When a row is enabled, its textboxes should be enabled and vice versa.

**UPDATE (Working)**

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cb-master').click(toggleCheckAll);
        $('#mappings input:checkbox[id^="cb"]').click(checkChildren);
        $('#mappings tbody tr[id^="child"] input:checkbox').change(toggleInputs);
    });

    function toggleCheckAll() {
        var selector = $(this).is(':checked')
                           ? '#mappings tbody input:checkbox:checked'
                           : '#mappings tbody input:checkbox:not(:checked)';

        $(selector).each(function () {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        });
    }

    function checkChildren() {
        var selector = ".child-of-" + $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked') ? ':not(:checked)' : ':checked';
        $(selector).find('input:checkbox' + isChecked).each(function () {
            $(this).trigger('click');
            $(this).change();
        });
    }    

    function toggleInputs() {
        var isChecked = $(this).attr('checked');
        var inputs = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text');

        if (isChecked)
            inputs.removeAttr('disabled');
        else
            inputs.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
</script>
```

This is what my table looks like:

```
<table id="mappings">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="cb-master"></th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Input</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="grandparent">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb-grandparent" /></td>
            <td>Grandparent</td>
            <td />
        </tr>
        <tr id="parent" class="child-of-grandparent">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb-parent" /></td>
            <td>Parent</td>
            <td />
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-1" class="child-of-parent">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb-child-1" /></td>
            <td>Child 1</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="child-2" class="child-of-parent">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb-child-2" /></td>
            <td>Child 2</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works when I manually check/uncheck each box, but it does not work when I do it programatically through the `toggleCheckAll()` function. Is there something I have to do to bind this event programitically as well?

Also, I am having difficulty implementing the `checkChildren` function recursively, as every time I attempt to I get the exception `nodeName is null or not an object`.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6U5nf/)

If instead of this:

```
 this.checked = isChecked;
```

try

```
 $(this).trigger('click');
```

To initially disable all input text, first do:

```
 $('input:text').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
 });
```

Does that answer your question? I wasn't able to test it out, but I assumed that by actually triggering a click event it would execute the rest of the code or instead of binding it to a click event you would bind it to a change event, that should also work.

Comment: This still leaves me with disabled inputs where the checkboxes are checked and also inverts the selection instead of pushing the `checked` value of the parent all the way down, however, it does solve the recursion issue.

Comment: @shuniar is there some other styles or js that you are missing from the question. I updated the jsfiddle and it seems to be working except the initializing of disabling the inputs which I don't see on your code?

Comment: all styles and js are included. the disalbe/enable is done through an html helper for mvc which determines if the `disabled` attribute should be added during the page render. The toggle works only when it is done by hand.. I've also updated my bind for the `toggleInputs` to the `click` event instead of the `change` event.

Comment: I've updated my source to include your recommendations. I have everything working except for the cascading enable of the inputs. I have to uncheck and recheck them in order to enable their inputs.

Comment: Once you check/uncheck the cascading should work, what you are saying is that you want the input text to be initally disabled until something is checked, right?

Comment: Yes and no. I want it disabled initialially unless it is pre-populated with a value. This part works. But I want to enable the inputs of the children when a parent is checked, this doesn't work. Enabling/disabling works with the direct box though.

Comment: I got it working, I had to manually fire the change event in the `each()` loop. I've udated my question.